# Remove Unicode characters within various ranges in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, replace, astral-plane

I'm trying to remove every Unicode character in a string if it falls in any the ranges below.

```
\uD800-\uDFFF
\u1D800-\u1DFFF
\u2D800-\u2DFFF
\u3D800-\u3DFFF
\u4D800-\u4DFFF
\u5D800-\u5DFFF
\u6D800-\u6DFFF
\u7D800-\u7DFFF
\u8D800-\u8DFFF
\u9D800-\u9DFFF
\uAD800-\uADFFF
\uBD800-\uBDFFF
\uCD800-\uCDFFF
\uDD800-\uDDFFF
\uED800-\uEDFFF
\uFD800-\uFDFFF
\u10D800-\u10DFFF
```

As an initial prototype, I tried to just remove characters within the first range by using a regex in the `replace` function.

```
var buffer = "he\udfffllo world";
var output = buffer.replace(/[\ud800-\udfff]/g, "");
d.innerText = buffer + " is replaced with " + output;
```

In this case, the character seems to have been replaced fine.

However, when I replace that with

```
var buffer = "he\udfffllo worl\u1dfffd";
var output = buffer.replace(/[\ud800-\udfff\u1d800-\u1dfff]/g, "");
d.innerText = buffer + " is replaced with " + output;
```

I see something unexpected. My output shows up as:

> he�llo worl᷿fd is replaced with

There are two things to note here:

1. `\u1dfff` does not show up as one character - `\u1dff` gets converted to a character and the `f` at the end it treated as its own character
2. the result is an empty string.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this would be much appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

My overall goal is to filter out all characters that the `encodeURIComponent` function considers invalid. I ran some tests and found the list above to be the set of characters that a invalid. For instance, the code below, which first converts `1dfff` to a unicode character before passing that to `encodeURIComponent` causes an exception to be raised by the latter function.

```
var v = String.fromCharCode(122879);
var uriComponent = encodeURIComponent(v);
```

I edited parts of the question after @Blender pointed out that i was using `x` instead of `u` in my code to represent Unicode characters.

---

**EDIT 2**

I investigated my technique for fetching the "invalid" unicode ranges further, and as it turns out, if you give `String.fromCharacterCode` a number that's larger than 16 bits, it'll just look at the lowest 16 bits of the number. That explains the pattern I was seeing. So as it turns out, I only need to worry about the first range.

Comment: `\xdfff` is interpreted as `\xdf`, `f` and `f`.

Comment: Ahh you're right, that explains why I was seeing weird results in my second attempt. Changing that part of the question now.

Comment: The notation `\u1D800` and most of the other notations are not valid at all (or, technically, `\u1D800`, means U+1D80 followed by the digit zero. Please formulate your question in terms of Unicode characters, not using assumed (and invalid) escape notations for them.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What I've often noticed on SO is that people who've have knowledge about a topic for a while often forget that others exploring the same topic don't know even the basics to formulate the question correctly. In fact, if they did, they'd be far enough along to have answered their question themselves, leaving the entire point of SO moot. I'm not advocating for laziness; I researched, but just didn't know the right keywords to put into a search engine, which is why I turned to SO. So I formulated my question the best I knew how and posted it here and even edited as I learned more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're trying to remove Unicode surrogate code units from the string. However, only U+D800 through U+DFFF are surrogate code points; the remaining values you name are not, and could be allocated to valid Unicode characters. In that case, the following will suffice (use `\u` rather than `\x` to refer to Unicode characters):

```
buffer.replace(/[\ud800-\udfff]/g, "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter. I've edited the question to include more details about how I came up with the list of characters that need to be removed. After i replaced the \x with \u, I stopped getting a syntax error, but I did notice some other interesting behavior which I've outlined in the edit. Thanks again for looking.

Comment: Dug into this further, and as it turns out, you're right in that I only need to worry about the first range. I've added an explanation in a second edit I made to the question.